# Transfer Learning on Resnet50 doesn't go beyond 40%

Tags: keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I'm using Kaggle - Animal-10 dataset for experimenting transfer learning with FastAI and Keras.

Base model is Resnet-50.

With **FastAI** I'm able to get accuracy of 95% in 3 epochs.

`learn.fine_tune(3, base_lr=1e-2, cbs=[ShowGraphCallback()])`

I believe it only trains the top layers.

With **Keras**

- If I train the complete Resnet then only I'm able to achieve accuracy of 96%
- If I use the below code for transfer learning, then at max I'm able to reach 40%

```
num_classes = 10
#number of layers to retrain from previous model
fine_tune = 33 #conv5 block
model = Sequential()

base_layer = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights="imagenet")
# base_layer.trainable = False 
#make only last few layers trainable, except them make all false
 for layer in base_layer.layers[:-fine_tune]:
             layer.trainable = False
model.add(base_layer)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
# model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
# model.add(layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

I assume the cause [Transfer learning with Keras, validation accuracy does not improve from outset (beyond naive baseline) while train accuracy improves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676652/transfer-learning-with-keras-validation-accuracy-does-not-improve-from-outset)

and thats the reason that now I'm re-training complete block5 of Resnet and still it doesn't add any value.